# Pin line/arrow to bar-chart elements

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, shapes

I'd like to pin some lines in order to follow the movement of stacked 100% bar-chart elements. As you can see from the screenshot below

*Right behavior* 
[image: Unfiltered]

the arrow are more or less in the middle of each block. If i use the left slicer filters to modify what I'm showing in the charts everything changes. As you can see now the lines are not centered anymore since the blocks shifted...

*Wrong behavior* 
[image: Filtered]

**Question**
*Is there a way to pin the lines with the block in order to have the right line pointing to the right block?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a combination chart.  Use a stacked column chart like you have presented.  Then add an XY/Scatter Chart for your leader lines.  You'll need to  create some helper columns to calculate where you want the end points to land (each side).  Then use the outside data points' labels for your line labels.  You can also use formatting of the XY series lines to emphasize points of interest.